# CSS spacing crisis

Tags: css, spacing

I've looked through your topics related to this and I've tried the solutions you've proposed but none have worked for me.

Everything on this page I'm making looks great, only the spacing below and above words are way off. Nothing I try seems to work. I just can't figure it out.

Below is the entire CSS code for it. I apologize but I wanted to be thorough. Maybe a fresh set of eyes will spot the problem.

*the area I'm having issues with is around #portcover

```
/* Body / Whole Document */

html, body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#666666;
}

.greeting {
    position:relative;
    margin:50px 0px 0px 200px;
    padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#A30000;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:agency fb;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:85px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#click {
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    left:200px;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    color:#FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:agency fb;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

#to {
    position:absolute;
    top:125px;
    left:200px;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    color:#FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:agency fb;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

#enter {
    position:absolute;
    top:225px;
    left:200px;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    color:#FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:agency fb;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.container {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:864px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.clear {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    width:960px;
    height:0px;
}

noscript {
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px 0px;
    top:50px;
    left:130px;
    width:60%;
    height:175px;
    background-color:#000;  
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
}

noscript a {
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

/*=================== Banner =======================*/

.banner {
    position:relative;
    margin:50px 0px 0px 200px;
    padding:0px;
    width:690px;
    height:150px;
    font-family:agency fb;
}

#logo {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:172.8px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:150px;
    background-color:#D11717;
    color:#FAFAFA;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:100px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#fullname {
    position:absolute;
    margin:-50px;
    padding:0px;
    top:100px;
    left:55px;
    width:600px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background-color:#D11717;
    color:#FAFAFA;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}


.topnav {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:690.3px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#transparent;
}

/*==================================== Portfolio =============================*/
#portfolio {
    position:relative;
    margin:-200px 0px 0px 175px;
    padding:0px;
    width:172.8px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:150px;
    color:#FAFAFA;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;  
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#portfolio:hover {
    background-color:#D11717;
    color:white;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

#portcover {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    margin:-50px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:525px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#921010;
    border-radius:0px 20px 20px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#portdiv {
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0px;
    width:515px;
    height:290px;
    background-color:#D11717;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
}

#portinfo {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
}

#portlinks {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin:-50px;
    padding:-50px;
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;

    outline:2px solid white;
}

#portdiv a {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 100px 0px 100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:150px;
}

#portdiv a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
    font-size:25px;
}

/*==================================================================*/

#contact {
    position:relative;
    margin:-200px 0px 0px 349px;
    padding:0px;
    width:172.8px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:150px;
    color:#FAFAFA;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;  
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#contact:hover {
    background-color:#D11717;
    color:white;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

#concover {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-50px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    top:150;
    right:200;
    width:525px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#921010;
    border-radius:20px 0px 20px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    outline:2px solid yellow;
}

#condiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:515px;
    height:290px;
    background-color:#D11717;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#condiv1a {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin:100px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;

    outline:2px solid white;
}

#condiv1b {
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;

    outline:2px solid white;
}

#about {
    position:relative;
    margin:-200px 0px 0px 523px;
    padding:0px;
    width:172.8px;
    height:100%;
    line-height:150px;
    color:#FAFAFA;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;  
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#about:hover {
    background-color:#D11717;
    color:white;
    border-radius:20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

#abcover {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-50px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    top:200px;
    right:0px;
    width:525px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#921010;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    border-radius:20px 0px 20px 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#abdiv {
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;
    width:495px;
    height:290px;
    background-color:#D11717;
    text-align:left;
    border-radius:20px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this with an entire CSS file and no HTML or specific case to work off. What does #portcover style? It's got a display:none on it so is it styling anything? By the spacing below and above words are you referring to line-height? It might be good to set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
 * {
line-height: 1.2em!important;
}
```

This will quickly show you if it's a line-height problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to the spacing of the text top to bottom, try using a line height with the value of the unit in px. I cant figure out the error if you will just give the css codes without the html markup